# c# concurrent ordered dictionary

Tags: c#, .net

For `Dictionary` there is `ConcurrentDictionary` which is thread safe and can be accessed by multiple threads concurrently. But for `OrderedDictionary` I found there is no `ConcurrentOrderedDictionary` type in c#.

So how can I implement a thread safe and concurrently accessable OrderedDictionary?

Comment: I don't think there is on in .Net... Search for thread safe binary search tree if you have to... Also take a look at [ImmutableSortedDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablesorteddictionary-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-2.2) and see if that's enough for your needs (inherently thread safe... but adding creates new instance).

Comment: Do you need a fastest dictionary implementation or “as fast as ordinary dictionary can be with a little slow down”. For the second, you can just have a composition class with locks inside basic `OrderedDictionary ` operations.